# What Is the error in the code, i want to replace a set of characters from a text file when i give a work with blanks in it

Tags: python

i want to replace a set of characters from a text file when i give a work with blanks in it like for example :

i gave the line `The Language Is _th_n !`
it should return python replacing `_` with text from a file like `text.txt`

i wrote this code please check once

````py
with open('data/text','r', encoding='utf8') as file:
    word_list = file.read()

def solve(message):
    hint = []
    for i in range(15,len(message) - 1):
        if message[i] != '\\':
            hint.append(message[i])
    hint_string = ''
    for i in hint:
        hint_string += i
    hint_replaced = hint_string.replace('_', '!')
    solution = re.findall('^'+hint_replaced+'$', word_list, re.MULTILINE)
    return solution```
````

Comment: A few things (ran out of time to look deeper): Why `for i in range(15,len(message) - 1)` starts at ther 15th character of your `message`? How could `message[i]` be `\\` which is two characters?  `for i in hint:
        hint_string += i` is the same as  `hint_string = ''.join.hint`.

Comment: Back to this. What are you trying to do here? What does `data/text` file look like? Given the input string of `The Language Is _th_n !` and whatever `data/text` looks like, what is the output? Please share sample inputs and desires results so we can help.